# STATE_CONNECTED doesn't mean it's really CONNECTED?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetoothadapter, bluetoothheadset

If we have a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset), it says :

> Android **only** supports one connected Bluetooth Headset **at a
> time**.

Also the explanation of `getConnectedDevices()` :

> Return the set of devices which are in state `STATE_CONNECTED`

The return type of the method is `List<BluetoothDevice>`, and it returns more than one in my case.
One for Galaxy Watch, one for Galaxy Buds.

I know how to tell which one is active at the moment.
The one currently being used will return true when `BluetoothHeadset.isAudioConnected()` is called.
So I'm not asking how to find the active Bluetooth headset device here.
I'm rather trying to understand what `STATE_CONNECTED` really means.

I think this is also useful to others because there are many answers like the following, which won't work as expected in some cases :

```
public static boolean isConnected() {
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    return  bluetoothAdapter != null
        && bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()
        && bluetoothAdapter.getProfileConnectionState(BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED;
}
```

This is not the proper one if you just want to check if your user is talking on the phone.
It's because the user's Bluetooth headset will become `STATE_CONNECTED` immediately after the Bluetooth headset is turned on and syncs with the smartphone.

So, what is `STATE_CONNECTED` exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation, `bluetoothAdapter.getProfileConnectionState(BluetoothProfile.HEADSET)` returns the current connection state of the `BluetoothProfile.HEADSET` profile.

This call returns `BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED` if the bluetooth adapter of the phone is currently connected to a device with the headset profile.

It does not mean the user is currently using the headset to talk. It means the headset is ready to handle communication with the phone.